# Getting around setters inside class

Tags: php, oop, setter, magic-methods

So I have just started using magic methods and ran into this problem when I have to bind variables to use in my function.

This is an little example of my problem

```
class test{
    protected $arraytest = array();
    function __construct(){
        $this->test = "datafor2";
        var_dump($this->arraytest);
    }
    function test(){
        return $this->test;
    }
    function __set($name, $value){
        $this->arraytest[$name] = $value;
    }
}
$test = new test();
echo $test->test();
```

So what I am trying to do it bind `test` for later use in the function `test()`, but because I am binding a variable to the object it uses the magic method and binds it accordinly to the setter. 
This is not the behavior I am looking for as the variable `$arraytest`, shouldn't have the variable `test`binded.

What ways can this be solved? I know I could just make an exception in the stter if the variable is `test`, just wondering what better practises there is when using magic setters.

Comment: Would `class test { private $test; .... ` work for you?

Comment: The "magic" setter only executes because `$this->test` doesn't exist; so surely the solution is to define `$this->test` explicitly

Comment: I'd think twice about using magic setter methods. One of the cornerstones of OO is encapsulation, and providing such methods basically tears it into pieces.

Comment: Oh wauw, didn't really think about just binding the variable first, well that actually seems like the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: @hasumedic, please explain why using setter methods tears it into pieces as the setter only has acces to bind variable's in an specific array.

Comment: @uruloke the reason you even have the question is because you had unintended consequences. If all you are doing is modifying an array why not have a functions like `setArraytest($name,$val)` and `getArraytest($name)`, I know it is tempting to use these magic functions but they can cause major headaches in the long run.

Comment: Well, I'd actually distinguish between DTOs/ValueObjects and Entities. If your `test` class is meant to be an entity (has a life-cycle and you can identify it by an ID), you should definitely not use magic setters. You should always be in control about when and how your object modifies its state. Also, ideally providing meaningful names to those functions that modify the internal state of the object.

Comment: @Pitchinnate, because I personally find it prettier that I can bind stuff to the class with `$test->newvariable = value` instead of `$test->setArraytest('newvariable', value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the variable as a property, and the setter won't be used.

```
class test{
    protected $arraytest = array();
    protected $test;

    function __construct(){
        $this->test = "datafor2";
        var_dump($this->arraytest);
    }
    function test(){
        return $this->test;
    }
    function __set($name, $value){
        $this->arraytest[$name] = $value;
    }
}
$test = new test();
echo $test->test();
```